# How to design the navigator structure of a React-Native Android app?

Tags: android, reactjs, navigation, react-native

I am building an Expense Keeping app with React-Native on Android. Below is the UI flow chart of my app:

1. I wish to use the Drawer to navigate between top level scenes (shown in dark red).
2. In the *Settings* scene, there are options that require to navigate to a group of 2nd level scenes which can only navigate back to the *Settings* scene (shown in blue).

[image]

I want my Navigation bar to persist across scene transitions, so I am using the [navigationBar props](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/navigator.html) of the `<Navigator>` component.

Using a single `<Navigator>` as the top component in my app and manage all the scenes and routes with it is an obvious solution but this way it is harder to manage the "levels" of scenes.

I would like to know if there are any other better ways to structure the `<Navigator>` in my app, perhaps nesting navigators?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know this is an old question, but it is still relevant and just to keep this up-to-date, use [React-Navigation](https://github.com/react-community/react-navigation/) (Warning: requires some learning and practice). You can use this [example](https://github.com/react-community/react-navigation/issues/582). Look out for the navigation tree in that. It is similar to what the question needs.

Comment: Thanks! I'm currently using react-navigation as well and it's great. RN's communities sure move fast!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [react-native-router-flux](https://github.com/aksonov/react-native-router-flux) component?

Answer (score -4):

You can using Fragment.

First: In Activity. You create Navigatior.
in xml of Activity have:

```
<DrawerLayout>

<Toolbar> or (Control Home of you)

<FrameLayout id="content_main">
```

Then: You create SettingFragment extend Fragment

HomeFragment extend Fragment

ExpansesFragment extend Fragment

```
import support.v4.Fragment
```

In Activity extend Activity

onCreate:

```
    FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    manager.beginTransaction()
            .setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN)
            .replace(R.id.content_main, HomeFragment)
            .commit();
```

On Drawer. event Onclick

```
Home

  FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    manager.beginTransaction()
            .setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN)
            .replace(R.id.content_main, HomeFragment)
            .commit();

Expenses

FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    manager.beginTransaction()
            .setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN)
            .replace(R.id.content_main, ExpensesFragment)
            .commit();


Category

  FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    manager.beginTransaction()
            .setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN)
            .replace(R.id.content_main, CategoryFragment)
            .commit();
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I believe this user is asking about React Native, which uses JavaScript to create mobile apps, rather than Java. So your answer isn't going to be useful to them.

Comment: this is java not react-native